# Windows Live/Azure 2 step verification

Tags: azure, windows-live

After reading about Mr. Honan's digital life being destroyed: http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/08/apple-amazon-mat-honan-hacking/all/, I started thinking about the login security of Windows Live and Windows Azure. Is there any kind of 2 step verification that can be applied to windows live/azure? Google's 2 step verification is great and this would be ideal, but I couldn't find anything on this topic.

Thanks,

Andrew Petersen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that your concern is valid to have 2 step verification with Windows Azure. As of now you can not implement 2-factors authentication by your own with Windows Azure as it has to be done in platform it self. I believe Windows Azure Product team is sincerely working on to address such concern in Windows Azure however I don't think this forum is not a good place to discuss those details.

Comment: Okay thanks, I was just wondering if something was already in place that I was missing.